# Mysql Derived Table Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, derived-table

I have a table with the following columns:

record_id

source_id

user_id

mobile

called_at

I am trying to run these two queries

```
SELECT
      t1.user_id,
      t1.mobile,
      COUNT(DISTINCT(t1.called_at )) AS cnt
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          user_id,
          mobile,
          called_at
        FROM
          users
        WHERE
          called_at >= "2016-09-01" AND called_at < "2016-12-01" and user_id is NOT NULL
      ) t1
    GROUP BY t1.user_id, t1.mobile
    HAVING cnt > 1
```

And

```
SELECT
      user_id,
      mobile,
      COUNT(DISTINCT(called_at )) AS cnt
      FROM users
      WHERE called_at >= "2016-09-01" AND called_at < "2016-12-01" and user_id is NOT NULL
    GROUP BY user_id, mobile
    HAVING cnt > 1
```

Both queries are logically same and also give same output. But the first query is running very quickly ~ 3 seconds and the second one ~ 55 seconds.

Even explain says that the first query involves extra scan on derived table using filesort and still its much faster.

How is this possbile?

Explain Output:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----------------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table                 | type | possible_keys         | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----------------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>            | ALL  | NULL                  | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1025150 | Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | users                 | ALL  | idx_fa_af,idx_a_di_um | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2221923 | Using where    |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----------------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+

+----+-------------+-----------------------+-------+-----------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                 | type  | possible_keys         | key         | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+-------+-----------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users                 | index | idx_fa_af,idx_a_di_um | idx_a_di_um | 23      | NULL | 2221923 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+-------+-----------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+

| users | CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `record_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `source_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `called_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_unique_a_ri_si` (`record_id`,`source_id`),
  KEY `idx_fa_af` (`called_at`),
  KEY `idx_fa_um` (`mobile`),
  KEY `idx_a_di_um` (`user_id`,`mobile`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |


+----------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name              | Value   |
+----------------------------+---------+
| Handler_commit             | 1       |
| Handler_delete             | 0       |
| Handler_discover           | 0       |
| Handler_external_lock      | 2       |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0       |
| Handler_prepare            | 0       |
| Handler_read_first         | 1       |
| Handler_read_key           | 1       |
| Handler_read_last          | 0       |
| Handler_read_next          | 0       |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0       |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 0       |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 3676447 |
| Handler_rollback           | 0       |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0       |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0       |
| Handler_update             | 0       |
| Handler_write              | 1208173 |
+----------------------------+---------+

+----------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name              | Value   |
+----------------------------+---------+
| Handler_commit             | 1       |
| Handler_delete             | 0       |
| Handler_discover           | 0       |
| Handler_external_lock      | 2       |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0       |
| Handler_prepare            | 0       |
| Handler_read_first         | 1       |
| Handler_read_key           | 1       |
| Handler_read_last          | 0       |
| Handler_read_next          | 2468272 |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0       |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 0       |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 0       |
| Handler_rollback           | 0       |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0       |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0       |
| Handler_update             | 0       |
| Handler_write              | 0       |
+----------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Post the EXPLAIN outputs also

Comment: Include the output from EXPLAIN.

Comment: Can you also post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` output?

Comment: updated the description.

Answer (score 1):

Add `INDEX(user_id, called_at, mobile)`, then run each query twice.  Twice is to avoid caching issues that could be hiding I/O.

I *suspect* that the first query ran fast because it was all in RAM.  And the second was using index `idx_a_di_um` which was not cached.

The index I am suggestion should make both of them run faster.

Is any combination of columns 'unique'?  If so, make the combination the `PRIMARY KEY`.  This will improve things further.  If not, at least provide a `id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`.

**Why it will help**

An index is a BTree. (See wikipedia for a good definition.)  That index structure is separate from the data, which is in a separate BTree, ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  A BTree is very efficient at finding a row or set of consecutive rows.  ("Consecutive" according to the index.)  When using a secondary key (ie, not `PRIMARY`), first the row(s) of the index are located, then each *data* row is looked up using the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Unless...  If *all* the columns that are needed in a `SELECT` are in the secondary key, there is no need to reach over to the data.  This is called 'covering'; `EXPLAIN` indicates it by saying "Using index".  My index is a "covering" index for the subquery.

The order of the columns in any index is important.  In this one case, the index has all `user_id IS NOT NULL` rows together.  But that is about the only argument for the order of the 3 columns.

**Handler trick**

Here's a way to get more insight into what a query is doing, it it does not depend on caching, server-restart, etc:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

Numbers that look like the size (rows) of the table indicate a table (or index) scan.  Numbers that look like the size of the output indicate some final manipulation.  Handler_write... indicates a tmp table.  Etc.

Comment: Hey i even tried running both queries by restarting the server. Still the same performance.
After i added the index you mentioned both run much faster now. The first one took 2.5 seconds and the second one 3.6 seconds. Still fails to explain why first one is faster.
Have updated description to add a unique key.
Could you also explain how that index helped in speeding things up?

Comment: Restarting the server gives you the worst I/O timing -- often not realistic, especially for a continually running production server.

Comment: Huh?  `record_id` and `source_id` are not listed in the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`??

Comment: I added  a technique for getting more insight.  Consider running that on both queries and presenting the results.  (At least the non-zero rows.)  _Maybe_ that will give us a clue as to why the first is faster.

Comment: Added "Why it will help".

Comment: So are you saying that i should have a index on (user_id, called_at, mobile) instead of an index on (user_id, mobile) or should i have both indexes.

Comment: A "covering" index is somewhat better; `(user_id, called_at, mobile)` is covering.  It would be OK to have both indexes, then use `EXPLAIN` to see which one it uses.

Comment: Have added output for handler.

Comment: The first Handler output shows a full table (or index) scan (2M rows), wrote half that many to a tmp table, then reread the tmp table.  The second looks considerably faster -- one full scan; no tmp table, no re-read.

Comment: Yes i notices that but then how is the second one slower. And i posted this data without adding the covering index.

Comment: Also can you explain how adding a covering index helped with the subquery. Because the subquery is just filtering on called_at and called_at is the second attribute in the covering index so it cant use that index to find the relevant rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130809/discussion-between-sidhant-and-rick-james).